# Where is the IcedTea Control Panel?

Tags: icedtea

I want to disable the sandbox banner on Java Webstart applications, and the [official documentation](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/IcedTea-Web#Configuration) hints at a control panel, but I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The IcedTea control panel is launched using the command `itweb-settings` from a terminal.

Comment: It is required to install `icedtea-netx` package.

Comment: It was installed by default on my Mint 17 laptop, it seems.